# save() on a Pyspark ML Word2vec model is creating empty folders

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, nlp, pyspark, word2vec

I'm trying to save a word2vec model that I built in pyspark on spark 2.0.

```
word2vec_model.write().overwrite().save('filepath/word2vec')
```

This successfully finishes and creates 2 sub-folders (data & metadata) under the folder word2vec but these 2 subfolders are empty except for an empty file titled _SUCCESS.

And subsequently the `load` fails.

```
w2vw = Word2Vec.load('filepath/word2vec')
```

with the exception: `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: empty collection`

The word2vec model itself works fine and I create it via series of simple transformers. I'm not sure what is going wrong. My model creation code snippet:

```
tokenizer = Tokenizer(inputCol="input", outputCol="words")
remover = StopWordsRemover(inputCol="words", outputCol="filtered_1")
customRemover = CustomRemover(inputCol="filtered_1",outputCol="filtered")
word2vec = Word2Vec(inputCol="filtered",vectorSize=100, minCount=10)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I fixed this problem with a little help. This question unfortunately doesn't highlight the area which was causing the problem. It was in the "filepath". I was writing to a local node instead of a distributed file system and that was causing a problem.

Answer (score 0):

as I think ,I guess you save word2vec model instead of word2vec,SO
for word2vec model you must read it by code below:

```
from pyspark.ml.feature import Word2VecModel
w2vw_model = Word2VecModel.load('filepath/word2vec')
```

and if you save just only word2vec that i mean this object:

```
word2vec = Word2Vec(inputCol="filtered",vectorSize=100, minCount=10)
word2vec.write().overwrite().save('filepath_to_just_word2vec_not_its_model')
```

you must import with this code blocks

```
w2vw = Word2Vec.load('filepath_to_just_word2vec_not_its_model')
```